# Why is runtime type checking so important in ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, runtime, typechecking

According to [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html), typescript is a static type checker for javascript. These checks take place during compile time, i. e. before the program execution. Ts creators also [state](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) that they do not provide runtime type information or runtime type checking. For this reason, many libraries have been created for runtime data validation in ts: io-ts, joi, yup, zod, etc. and best practice seems to dictate that we use them.

Can someone maybe explain why is runtime type checking so important?
What kind of errors can occur without it?
Do you maybe have some practical examples?

Comment: What happens when the data you actually get (from an API, file, user input, ...) isn't the shape you told the compiler it would be?

Comment: `function foo(x: number) { return number.toFixed(); }` and then call it with `const y: any = "hello"; foo(y)`. See what happens.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I suppose I wouldn't be able to map the input to my data structures and the outcome wouldn't be very nice :) But any language requires that we validate external input at runtime, right? In this case, a language that checks types at runtime wouldn't have an advantage over ts..

Comment: @VLAZ I see, thx for sharing. A whole app could be affected by such errors. I suppose lint rules could offer some protection.

Comment: The problem is the `any`. Linting cannot tell you what it is. There are lint rules to disable `any` and, IMO, worth enabling. However, at boundary points of the system, you can't really do much. `fetch(url)` can return `{hello: "foo"}` today but start returning `{world: "bar"}` tomorrow without any change to the JS/TS code.

Answer (score 4):

Let say you have an api like https://yesno.wtf/api, it returns a json like that:

```
{
  "answer": "no",
  "forced": false,
  "image": "https://yesno.wtf/assets/no/20-56c4b19517aa69c8f7081939198341a4.gif"
}
```

But you can also type it like this:

```
type ResponseData = {
  answer: number[],
  forced: string,
  image: boolean[]
}
```

TypeScript will say it's fine, but it's isn't, it will throw errors in run time when you will try to do something like

```
image.map(() => /* */)
```

Because `image` is not really an array